# How to allow specific program through Linux firewall?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, ufw

I have ufw/gufw with the following rules:

Deny all incoming and also deny all outgoing.

Now I want to add an exception to these rules:

Let's say I have a custom web browser named MyBrowser and I want to allow just this program to connect to the internet while browsing but just to the port 80 (and for the sake of this example just 80 but blocked on 443).

In gufw/ufw you can see a list of programs but this program is not on the list since it's a custom one. (Even installed programs like Chrome or Firefox are not in the list.)

Also, I tried:

```
sudo ufw allow MyBrowser
```

But it is not working saying that MyBrowser profile can't be found.
Also, I want it to be just for the port 80 and since adding rule above is not working, sudo ufw allow MyBrowser 80 I think will not work either.

Next, I tried:

```
sudo ufw allow 80
```

But this is not what I want, I want that only MyBrowser to be able to use port 80 and no other browser or any other programs.

How to achieve this, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you checked https://askubuntu.com/a/488647 ?

Comment: @criztovyl I did that already but it blocks everything also if allow it it just can run anything on that specified port but I want just MyBrowser and anything else.

Comment: you might want to have a look at opensnitch https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch

Comment: @criztovyl this is what I need. Thank you!